# embedded c insufficient memory

Tags: embedded

Hii I am beginer in embedded C programming and using code composer studio for building project on launchpad MSP430.But while bulding project on this board I got error saying " no valid memory range(null) available for placement of .text"

Below is my code:

```
SECTIONS
{
.bss        : {} > RAM                  /* GLOBAL & STATIC VARS              */
.data       : {} > RAM                  /* GLOBAL & STATIC VARS              */
.sysmem     : {} > RAM                  /* DYNAMIC MEMORY ALLOCATION AREA    */
.stack      : {} > RAM (HIGH)           /* SOFTWARE SYSTEM STACK             */

 .text        : {} > FLASH // Here it says  program will not fit into 
                           // available memory.  placement with alignment 
                           // fails for section ".text" size 0x499a.

.cinit      : {} > FLASH                /* INITIALIZATION TABLES             */
.const      : {} > FLASH                /* CONSTANT DATA                     */
.cio        : {} > RAM                  /* C I/O BUFFER                      */

.pinit      : {} > FLASH                /* C++ CONSTRUCTOR TABLES            */
.init_array : {} > FLASH                /* C++ CONSTRUCTOR TABLES            */
.mspabi.exidx : {} > FLASH              /* C++ CONSTRUCTOR TABLES            */
.mspabi.extab : {} > FLASH              /* C++ CONSTRUCTOR TABLES            */

.infoA     : {} > INFOA              /* MSP430 INFO FLASH MEMORY SEGMENTS */
.infoB     : {} > INFOB
.infoC     : {} > INFOC
.infoD     : {} > INFOD
```

Comment: Those are secrions, but to understand we need sizes of your code and of sections. Could you paste your linker script and  map fil, please?

Answer (score 1):

The .txt section contains the program segment and ends up landing into the flash of your microcontroller. Here your code's text section is larger than the space available.

Answer (score 1):

the probable reasons for that error :
you didn't use the correct linker script file for this 
controller ,OR your code size is too large to fit in the .txt
so try to use a simple code in size and build it,
if it runs correctly so the linker script file is OK , if not so the cause of that error is the code size ,
so you have two options in that case.
1-optimize the code to reduce the size of it.
2- modify the linker script file and increase the 
.txt section against other flash sections like Const data section

Answer (score 0):

*"MSP430 Launchpad"* is a name used for a [series of boards](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-msp430.html#tabs) with 16, 64 or 128Kb of flash memory.  Your `.text` segment is a little over 18Kb.  If you have a 16Kb board, it will of course not fit.

You might try applying compiler optimisations, but that will affect the ease with which you application may be debugged.  It may also be possible to improve the space efficiency of the code at the source level, especially if you have linked large or complex libraries such as C math or stdio or used floating point operations where integer or fixed point could be used.